# Use of pronouns with "and"

Tags: sentence

Which would be correct:

> Bill is making a cake for Karin and I

or

> Bill is making a cake for Karin and myself

Answer (score 0):

**Neither.** "Bill is making a cake for Karin and me." One trick you can use to quickly figure this out is to remove "...Karin and..." so that the sentence reads, "Bill is making a cake for me."  In your sentences, this would work out to "Bill is making a cake for I" and "Bill is making a cake for myself." The latter is using a reflexive pronoun to refer to the subject, which is Bill. This doesn't work because you are not Bill.

**Update:**

Here are a few links that may be helpful:

http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/between-you-and-me.aspx
http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/myself-grammar.aspx